# How to display a flash message in login page

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 3.2.7 along with spring-security-core:3.1.1, I want to set a message to the flash object from a controller upon logout, then I need to display this message in my login screen (auth.gsp)

see the below code I wrote.

In controller

```html
if(condition 1){ 
flash.message = "logged out successfully and your claim id is 12345"; redirect(uri:"/logout"); 
}else if(condition b){ 
flash.message = "logged out"; redirect(uri:"/logout"); 
}else if(condition c){ 
flash.message = "multiple login is not allowed"; redirect(uri:"/logout"); 
}
```

In the auth.gsp

```
<g:if test='${flash.message}'>
<div class="login_message">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

I could not see this message. Does anyone know how to display this message?

Comment: Check the answer for the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185261/grails-spring-security-core-plugin-adding-flash-message-to-login-page?rq=1

Comment: @Sankar this example is not applicable in my case. Here if the user is not logged in then the application should redirect to the login page. (By direct calling of login controller, no logout is happening). In my case I'm already logged in and I want to logout first then need to display the flash object in login screen. You may know that when we logout from the application the entire session and flash objects will be invalidated.

Comment: You want to show them you are logged out right?

Comment: Yes, I wanna show them after logging out

Comment: You can achieve it without flash object

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I have answered check it out..!

Comment: You can try to use cookies, you can catch logout event and put message into cookies, and then display that on login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not redirected to the auth page when you logout, you will not see the flash message.

Find out which page you are redirected to and this code.

```
<g:if test='${flash.message}'>
<div class="login_message">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

If you really want to see this message on the auth page, then make sure logout redirects you directly to the auth page.

Have you thought about using sessions?

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html

Unlike flash message, they exist until you reset them. Flash messages are reset after the first time you request them.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it is redirecting to the auth.gsp. Here the problem is I'm logging out the user after setting the flash message. Both session and flash map will be invalidated upon logout, I want to know how to overcome this issue. In other words how to prevent flash map from getting deleted on logout. Or any way to exclude a particular session attribute from getting deleted on logout.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting to the auth page with a GET params eg. login/auth?message=true. In your auth gsp, put a if condition that will check this param and hide/display the message as necessary.

Comment: calling the url login/auth?message=true will cause some problems. Actually it will redirect to the login screen, but no logout action will happen there. In other words a browser back button click can retain the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for @Abilash

In your controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
        @RequestParam(value = "expired", required = false) String expired,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", getErrorMessage(request, "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"));
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }

    if (expired != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "Session Timeout..!");

    }

    model.setViewName("login");

    return model;

}
```

And your View

```
<div class="error" style="color: red;" align="center">${error}</div>
```

In your spring security config

for Error

```
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
```

for Logount

```
.and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Comment: Updated the question please see, In this scenario does your code work?

Comment: In my answer, I'm not using flash object, it will identify the status (logout / error) by the RequestParam. Here, no need to create a new RequestMapping for logout.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the logout in spring security